# Excel Saving Loop / Cannot Save Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with simple VBA to refresh page, saved as `.xlsm`

I've noticed 2 types of errors:

1. **Saving loop**, when an edit is made, and the save button is clicked - it goes into what I like to call saving loop - you have to eventually crash out.
2. **Saving Error** , Sometimes it just returns a 'Document not saved' error when you try to save, it attempts to fix the error and then eventually says not successful

This error is more likely to happen when users copy and paste into the document, or move another worksheet into the document, and then try to save.

Again, this document isn't doing anything complicated, a simple macro to refresh the page with a macro button.(actual macro is written by another add-in, just a one-line refresh worksheet - I use the add-in everyday for other files so 100% sure it's not the VBA code written by this add-in)

Every now and then, I create a new one from scratch as per the usual advice but soon enough this happens again.

Any similar experience / help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's you code? Could you post the relevant parts that would help us understand how you're doing it?

Comment: Yup, some code would be nice. It's like when you go to the doctor and say you have a bad knee but you won't get your knee out.